# AngularJS UI-Bootstrap Typeahead no matches

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I've been searching around so but found no question relating to this.

I am using Angular UI-bootstrap typeahead.

So I have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="loc" typeahead="location for location in filteredLocations = (locations | filter:$viewValue)" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" />
```

When I type it shows the options in the typeahead-popup div. But what should I do to show, when there are no matches, on that same popup "No matches found"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not that much idea, but what to do is, find out if match.length <= 0 then push one item into items array one item which should be not selectable else remove the last pushed item.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is create your own results listing. That's easy using `typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"` and this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
      <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>
```

If there are no results, return one element indicating there's no result. In the ng-template you can put a ng-if which checks if it's the no-results element and make it not clickable. That way the user can't choose "no results".

Comment: Hi @gidomanders, what exactly do you mean by "return one element indicating there's no result"? Thanks

Comment: I mean use a function instead of an inline filter and in your filter function return an empty element or an element indicating no match was found. Then in the ng-template check if the result contains that element using ng-if or ng-show/ng-hide. If so, display the "no match found", otherwise display the results.

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to make the element non clickable?

Comment: Instead of using an anchor, just use another element, like a span or a paragraph. So use ng-if "not empty" <a> and ng-if "empty" another element.

Comment: I was trying that but the span appears to still be clickable. Do you mind having a look at this and seeing if you can spot what I'm doing wrong http://plnkr.co/edit/iWoq5J4dUhT5xqBQmPyh?p=preview

Comment: Add a `if (company.companyname === 'No Results')` in the companySelected function and you're good to go.

Comment: Trouble is, when the no results item is clicked on, the typeahead selectMatch method which surrounds the list item is triggered and 'No Results' ends up in the text input. Thanks for your help anyway. I think I'm going to end up just inspecting the number of results returned from the service, and if the number is 0 then set the visibility of a similar styled 'No Results' div.

Comment: That's why you need the if in the selectedCompany, you have to return false or clear the input yourself when it's clicked. Good luck!

Comment: save the input text on ng-change, then in the select function, place the saved text into the model.

Comment: How will this work if you use "typeahead-popup-template-url". I have a 'Create New' button to show along with "No results found" but with "typeahead-popup-template-url", the drop-down is not triggered if you don't have any results. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The UI Bootstrap website shows a directive `typeahead-no-results="noResults"`. Then it has `<div ng-show="noResults">` with a glyphicon and the message "No Results Found". The full code is:

```
<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```