# make typeahead search not found non clickable

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have following markup for type ahead which works fine, now the problem is I want to disabled click when no match is found basically make it non s selectable.

```
<a tabindex="-1"  ng-if = " 'no results found' == match.model.formatted" ng-disabled>
            <span> No Results Found</span>
        </a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs : Showing no search result in typeahead when no match is found for entered string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343504/angularjs-showing-no-search-result-in-typeahead-when-no-match-is-found-for-ent)

Comment: the thread doesnt provide the ans im looking for